# Google Places API language=en returns results in other languages

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm sending the request like this:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?&key=ENTER_YOUR_KEY_HERE&name=&types=restaurant&location=35.79067650569248,107.49634109437466&radius=521711.0&language=en

The query is in China.

and i'm getting results like this:

```
results: [
    {
    geometry: {
    location: {
    lat: 35.737293,
    lng: 107.646029
    }
    },
    icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
    id: "759bdf36fa8d5182c6cecb8839d21f5db691ab04",
    name: "海底捞火锅西峰店",
    place_id: "ChIJwQHr9-k9ZjYRkNpSDzYpfTo",
    reference: "CnRrAAAAkM6HlYVwL2mO2sefdojOY7cqX9lQtA_OWt2pFzyGW7p6lj-1oSqFnX3q7_iJtDBGIcoRhqMxriUEXCD4Y8QaBZXhX_7IiqgO_2xHYHN9nWEKOYuPWmuj1V5nTy-D_w-im2OcZVoblKayGDuo2xJTiBIQ2DySEk1zgG1UDKHFnzBxTRoUqsR3fT9UOHrRwOj-hQZZygqxiWo",
    scope: "GOOGLE",
    types: [
    "restaurant",
    "food",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
    ],
    vicinity: "Xifeng, Qingyang"
    },
```

the name is in Chinese. is there something i can do?

Comment: Well the documentation says *The language code, indicating in which language the results should be returned, **if possible**.* So I guess if *not possible* it will return in a different language. Chinese in this case?

Comment: Yes but maybe i should clarify, the data returns in a mix of English and Chinese. I get also results in English (which is good, for my needs). But i want JUST English, nothing else. I'm not exactly sure what "if possible" means.

Comment: The name is as it has been defined( by the creator/owner of the place:  https://plus.google.com/115570956297173610707/about ). Use a translation-service when you want to translate it

Comment: Well I think that if a translation in English was entered for the place, then you will see it, and if not, you will have the place name in the original language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MrUpsidown in the comments is correct: there's no English name for this place in Google's database, so returning the Chinese name Google does have is the best the Places API can do here.